# Save some data from html page to .csv or .txt

Tags: parsing

I'am not a programmer. So...

How can I make a program which get some data from dynamically added rows in some html page (many numbers on the many different pages) and save it automatically to .csv or .txt file every single day on my hard drive (or google cloud sheets)?

With which programming language, or ready program can I comfortable doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know little bit programming you can use HTML dom parser
Here link to Manual:

[Manual for HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do without any programming involved is to use a screen scraper plugin for your browser.  This isn't going to do it automatically on a daily basis though.  Chrome has one...  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screenscraper/pfegffhjcgkneoemnlniggnhkfioidjg